# How to build an Ubuntu container & install multiple programs

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I looked around and it doesn't appear that this question has been asked before but I may have missed it.

I'm trying to build a super basic ubuntu container and install several different things on it.

In the past I've built a python container with the line

```
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r program/requirements.txt
```

so every python dependency I need is in `requirements.txt`

What I'd like is some way for my to create a requirements.txt for my Ubuntu container that could contain something like

```
vim
apache2-utils
etc
```

and then in my Dockerfile just say

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install program/requirements.txt
```

Is there a way to do that? Or am I just going to have to include every requirement in the Dockerfile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every Dockerfile I’ve written has explicitly listed them out

```sh
RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends --assume-yes \
      ca-certificates \
      curl \
      python3
```

Also note that with multi-stage Dockerfiles it’s very reasonable to have two separate lists of packages you need, one to build the application and one to run it.

Answer (score 0):

`sed 's/#.*//' program/requirements.txt | xargs apt-get install`

You can even have comments in requirements.txt with this `sed` trick